# react-select-plus + Every backspace Removes call load option method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

How to call every backspace remove call load option. I am using select.Async control in every input change method call fetch method and fetch data but when I press backspace then first time called that load option method but in next time that can't call load option method.

```js
getUsers = (input) => {
console.log(input);
if (!input) {
return Promise.resolve({ options: [] });
}
if (input.length > 2) {
const newstate = this.state;
newstate.loadingtext = 'Searching...';
this.setState({ newstate });
const searchLocation = Object.assign({}, cookie.load('cLocation'));
searchLocation.searchText = input;
searchLocation.isBusiness = false;
console.log(input.toString().length);
return fetch(sourceName.searchNavbar, apiUrl.locationAndBusiness,
searchLocation)
.then(json => ({ options: json.data }));
}
return null;
}
```

```html
<Select.Async
onChange={this.onChange}
valueKey="placeID"
filterOptions={this.filterOptions}
labelKey="cityState"
loadOptions={this.getUsers}
onInputChange={inp => this.onInputChange(inp)}
onBlur={this.onBlur}
onInputKeyDown={inp => this.onInputKeyDown(inp)}
onFocus={this.onFocousSearch}
value={this.state.value}
searchPromptText="Please enter 3 or more characters"
loadingPlaceholder={this.state.loadingtext}
noResultsText="No results found"
options={this.state.options}
placeholder={this.state.placeholdervalue}
autoBlur

/>
```

In above code in load option that get user method call. My get User method is :

When I click first time back space then get user method call but in second time I pressed back space then not called that get user method. How to call every backspace remove call this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved my self using cache property in react-select-plus plugin. give that false like this cache={false}. so every time call getuser() method.